# Array of objects in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to define an array of objects (my defined class) of the same type in python.

I tried to use an array module:

```
from array import *
arrayIdentifierName = array("ClassName",[ClassName1,ClassName2,ClassName3])
```

it says:

```
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be char, not str
```

Then I tried to use a list:
Using list won't help since I don't see a method in http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html that can reach each object without removing it from the list (for example: list.pop([i]) or list.remove(x) will remove the object and I need to change one of it's data members and save it).

Any suggestion guys?

Thanks

Comment: Use indexing, like `yourList[i]`? Or simple iteration over the list with `for... in`?

Comment: you should be using lists, not arrays. In python, you don't need to use arrays unless you really know what you're doing

Comment: Thanks it works fine with yourList[i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U should be using list....
You can access any object using list and do whatever you want to do using its functions.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def show(self):
        print self.name

ob1=test('object 1')
ob2=test('object 2')

l=[]
l.append(ob1)
l.append(ob2)

l[0].show()
l[1].show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful if you wish to use inheritance.

```
class y:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s=s
    def f2(self):
        return 1 + self.s
   
class w():
    def t(self,n):
        y1 = y(n)
        return [y1]

a = [10,20,30]
j = w()
fn = []
for i in range(3):
        [x] = j.t(a[i])
        fn.append(x)

print(fn[0].f2())
print(fn[1].f2())
print(fn[2].f2())'
```